# how can i find cookie of new registration user and use its value in partial view mvc3?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, cookies

i have two methodes : one for registering new user **AddNewUser(MemberRegisterModel mm)** , and another for creating cookie for him  **CreateCookie(MemberLoginModel member)**.
i want to use this cookie that has been created after registering to show username top of all page until he log off.

i traced my code and saw cookie was created.
i use this code in **HeaderPartial.cshtml** to give username from cookie.

```
<div id="top">
@if (HttpContext.Current.Response.Cookies[FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName] != null)
  {
    HttpCookie cookie =
    HttpContext.Current.Request.Cookies.Get(FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName);
    var formAuthTicket = FormsAuthentication.Decrypt(cookie.Value);
    string CookieValue = formAuthTicket.UserData.ToString();
    <text> welcome <b> @Html.Label(CookieValue)</b>! 
    [@Html.ActionLink("Log off", "logout", "Members", new { area = "Members" }, null)]
    </text>
}
else
{
 <text>Welcome Guest!</text>
    @:[ @Html.ActionLink("Log in", "Login", "Members", new { area = "Members" }, null)]

}
```

but it doesn't work and shows error on this line:

```
    var formAuthTicket = FormsAuthentication.Decrypt(cookie.Value);
```

error:

> Invalid value for 'encryptedTicket' parameter.

what should i do?
i want to show username top of all page, and all username's db values in personal page of him.
and he will be log on and surf all page until he sign out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you write the authentication cookie using FormsAuthentication, you do not need to decrypt and read the raw cookie value. You can just use `@User.Identity.Name` in your views.

```
public ActionResult AddNewUser(MemberRegisterModel mm)
{
    ...
    FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(mm.UserName, true || false);
    ...
    return Redirect("Index", "Home");
}


Hello, and welcome, <strong>@User.Identity.Name</strong>
```

This is what SetAuthCookie looks like internally:

```
public static void SetAuthCookie(string userName, bool createPersistentCookie)
{
    FormsAuthentication.Initialize();
    FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(userName, createPersistentCookie, 
        FormsAuthentication.FormsCookiePath);
}

public static void SetAuthCookie(string userName, bool createPersistentCookie, 
  string strCookiePath)
{
  FormsAuthentication.Initialize();
  HttpContext current = HttpContext.Current;
  if (!current.Request.IsSecureConnection && FormsAuthentication.RequireSSL)
    throw new HttpException(System.Web.SR.GetString("Connection_not_secure_creating_secure_cookie"));
  bool flag = CookielessHelperClass.UseCookieless(current, false, FormsAuthentication.CookieMode);
  HttpCookie authCookie = FormsAuthentication.GetAuthCookie(userName, createPersistentCookie, flag ? "/" : strCookiePath, !flag);
  if (!flag)
  {
    HttpContext.Current.Response.Cookies.Add(authCookie);
    current.CookielessHelper.SetCookieValue('F', (string) null);
  }
  else
    current.CookielessHelper.SetCookieValue('F', authCookie.Value);
}

private static HttpCookie GetAuthCookie(string userName, bool createPersistentCookie, string strCookiePath, bool hexEncodedTicket)
{
  FormsAuthentication.Initialize();
  if (userName == null)
    userName = string.Empty;
  if (strCookiePath == null || strCookiePath.Length < 1)
    strCookiePath = FormsAuthentication.FormsCookiePath;
  DateTime utcNow = DateTime.UtcNow;
  DateTime expirationUtc = utcNow.AddMinutes((double) FormsAuthentication._Timeout);
  FormsAuthenticationTicket ticket = FormsAuthenticationTicket.FromUtc(2, userName, utcNow, expirationUtc, createPersistentCookie, string.Empty, strCookiePath);
  string str = FormsAuthentication.Encrypt(ticket, hexEncodedTicket);
  if (str == null || str.Length < 1)
    throw new HttpException(System.Web.SR.GetString("Unable_to_encrypt_cookie_ticket"));
  HttpCookie httpCookie = new HttpCookie(FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName, str);
  httpCookie.HttpOnly = true;
  httpCookie.Path = strCookiePath;
  httpCookie.Secure = FormsAuthentication._RequireSSL;
  if (FormsAuthentication._CookieDomain != null)
    httpCookie.Domain = FormsAuthentication._CookieDomain;
  if (ticket.IsPersistent)
    httpCookie.Expires = ticket.Expiration;
  return httpCookie;
}
```

Notice that it does in fact create a forms authentication ticket and encrypts the cookie,

Comment: SetAuthCookie creates an encrypted forms authentication ticket internally.

Comment: thx @danludwig, it is so complicated for me :D, if i want to add another things in cookie, what should i do? should i use session?
i am new in mvc and programming and it is my first project. sorry if i ask silly question...

Comment: You should not try to put anything else in the authentication cookie. If you want to store other things, either store them in separate cookies, or session, or database.

Comment: in my question i have just saved username in cookie. but, you think that i have saved some other things in my cookie and i want to retreive them from my partial view, how can i do it?

Comment: the code above, in <div id="top"></div> is in my headerPartial.cshtml and it located top of my register view, therefor, it will be check befor new user registers. it should be check after new user logs in.
what should i do for it?

Comment: To check whether or not a user is signed on, check `if (Request.IsAuthenticated) {`. When this returns false, display "Welcome Guest" along with the login link.